# jQuery Cookies: Remember Sate of Bootstrap Panel Heading

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, cookies

I would like to use jQuery Cookies to retain the state of my Bootstrap accordion. So far, this code is working well, but it only retains the state of the `.panel .panel-collapse` element.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
        //when a group is shown, save it as the active accordion group
        jQuery("#checkout-accordion").on('shown.bs.collapse', function () {
            var active = jQuery("#checkout-accordion .in").attr('id');
            jQuery.cookie('activeAccordionGroup2', active);
          //  alert(active);
        });
        jQuery("#checkout-accordion").on('hidden.bs.collapse', function () {
            jQuery.removeCookie('activeAccordionGroup2');
        });
        var last = jQuery.cookie('activeAccordionGroup2');
        if (last != null) {
            //remove default collapse settings
            jQuery("#checkout-accordion .panel-collapse").removeClass('in');
            //show the account_last visible group
            jQuery("#" + last).addClass("in");
        }
    });
```

I would need another piece of code that sets the cookie for the `.panel-heading` element. It should remember class `collapsed` when the accordion panel is collapsed, and remove class `collapsed` when it's toggled/active.

There's also this code, which works well too, but only for the `.panel .panel-collapse` element, and not for `.panel-heading` also.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

  var lastState = localStorage.getItem('lastState');

  if (!lastState) {
    lastState = [];
    localStorage.setItem('lastState', JSON.stringify(lastState));
  } else {
    lastStateArray = JSON.parse(lastState);
    var arrayLength = lastStateArray.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
        var panel = '#'+lastStateArray[i];
        $(panel).addClass('in');
    }
  }

  jQuery('#checkout-accordion').on('shown.bs.collapse', '.panel-collapse', function() {
    lastState = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('lastState'));
    if ($.inArray($(this).attr('id'), lastState) == -1) {
        lastState.push($(this).attr('id'));
    };
    localStorage.setItem('lastState', JSON.stringify(lastState));
  });

  jQuery('#checkout-accordion').on('hidden.bs.collapse', '.panel-collapse', function() {
    lastState = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('lastState'));
    lastState.splice( $.inArray($(this).attr('id'), lastState), 1 ); 
    localStorage.setItem('lastState', JSON.stringify(lastState));
  });

});
```

Any ideas?

Comment: jQuery Cookies is no longer maintained, you can maybe have a look at [jsCookie](https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie)

Comment: @Nora I don't much care what library I use as long as it does what it should. But thanks for the heads-up!